# How to Create a PowerShell ISE Tile

Tags: windows-8, powershell

I would like to create a PowerShell ISE tile in Windows 8.  I emphasise ISE, as when I search for PowerShell ISE, sure enough I can Pin to Start and create a tile, but despite the label 'PowerShell ISE, it's really plain PowerShell; that is the command line version and not the GUI ISE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Navigate to `%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
2. Right click on `PowerShell_ISE.exe`
3. Select "Pin to Start"